# Sword-and-sorcery flick from the 80s with a magic scarf that saves the hero's life

Tags: story-identification, movie, sword-and-sorcery

The only thing I can remember about this 80s sword-and-sorcery movie is that the knight received a green scarf from a (possibly magical) maiden/princess, and at the very end of the film, his enemy attempted to decapitate him, but due to the magic of the scarf it passed **through his neck,** allowing him to get up and fight for his life.

I cannot remember the actors, much of the story or any other details.

Also, it had a visual and cinematic aesthetic similar to *Krull*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This may be [*Sword of the Valiant: The Legend of Sir Gawain and the Green Knight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_the_Valiant), a 1984 adaptation of the story of [Sir Gawain and the Green Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Gawain_and_the_Green_Knight).

> Gawain rides out to meet the Knight. He has around his neck a piece of magical cloth from the lady, showing her favor. The Green knight takes aim with his axe at Gawain's neck and strikes a blow. To his surprise the Green Knight's strike only cuts the magical cloth given to him by the lady, leaving Gawain otherwise unharmed.

Comment: The New Hampshire television station WMUR seemed to show this movie a lot about 20 years ago.

Comment: @jwodder Just took a look at the trailer; yes this looks to be it. Thank you.

Comment: Blast from the past! I owned that on a VHS video